# Warning: require_once() with open_basedir restriction error - File not within allowed path(s)

Tags: php

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzonF.png)

I am encountering an error message while running my phpMyAdmin.The error message states:

```
Warning: require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/php/Composer/CaBundle/autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share
```

It seems to be related to the **open_basedir** directive, which is restricting access to the file **/usr/share/php/Composer/CaBundle/autoload.php**. The file is located outside the allowed path(s) specified in the open_basedir directive.

I have checked the **php.ini** file and verified that the open_basedir directive is indeed set to restrict access to specific directories. However, I need to include the file **autoload.php** for my application to function properly.

How can I resolve this error and allow access to the required file within the restricted environment? Is there a way to modify the **open_basedir** directive or make an exception for this specific file? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.